# How to edit patch items in a Kustomization file for doing gitops with Helm (and avoiding patches piling up)

Tags: helm, gitops, kustomize

I'm looking for a better way to update docker images defined ina HelmRelease using GitOps, as my current method is generating noise.

After introducing Helm to a cluster I'm managing with GitOps, I'm finding some difficulties on how to properly declare new docker image builds to be used in the cluster.

In a deployment I can use a simple Kustomization resource to replace image elements, e.g.:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: my-namespace

resources:
- namespace.yaml
- my-deployment.yaml

images:
- name: my/image
  newName: my/image
  newTag: updated-tag
```

and with every new build I simply modify the file with

```
kustomize edit set image my/image=my/image:updated-tag
```

Now with Helm I cannot use the same trick, as I need to update the tag `spec.values.image` in a HelmRelease, and Kustomize does not seem to have a shorthand for that. So the option is to create a patch:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: my-namespace

resources:
- namespace.yaml
- my-helm-release.yaml

patches:
- patch: '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/values/image", "value": "my/image:updated-tag"}]'
  target:
    kind: HelmRelease
    name: my-helm-release
    namespace: my-namespace
```

by using a similar command:

```
kustomize edit add patch \
    --kind HelmRelease \
    --name my-helm-release \
    --namespace my-namespace --patch "[{\"op\": \"replace\", \"path\": \"/spec/values/image\", \"value\": \"my/image:updated-tag\"}]"
```

(don't mind much the quoted quotes, bear with me)

The problem comes when running multiple times this command. While the `kustomize edit set image` overwrites the previous value, in this later case a new `patch` is appended to the list with the `more-updated-tag`.

```
patches:
- patch: '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/values/image", "value": "my/image:updated-tag"}]'
  target:
    kind: HelmRelease
    name: my-helm-release
    namespace: my-namespace
- patch: '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/values/image", "value": "my/image:more-updated-tag"}]'
  target:
    kind: HelmRelease
    name: my-helm-release
    namespace: my-namespace
```

How can I avoid this repetition and adding more and more noise to my files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a cleaner way to do it with [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).

```
yq -ei '.spec.values.image.tag = "YOURTAG"' yourfile.yaml
```